# Working with hidden files and files\folders that have spaces in the name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have made a script that takes all of the files in the current directory, checks if it is a regular file or a folder and sets permissions to them.

My problem is when I encounter hidden files\folders and files\folders that have spaces in the name.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=$(pwd)/*
for f in $FILES
  do
  if [ -f $f ]; then chmod u+x $f; fi
  if [ -d $f ]; then chmod u=w,g+r,o-rwx $f; fi
done
```

Here is an example of an error I get from the testing computer:

'test/.bwhajtbzmu   xswxcgqsvz' has incorrect permissions: expected 250, got 414.

The other errors are basically the same.

I am not actually sure what is the problem here, if it is the fact that it is a hidden file or that it has a space in the name. I guess both things are the problem.

How can I modify the script so that it can work with hidden files and files that have space in the name ?

Thank you

PS. Please don't question the usefulness of the script, it is a school homework.

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden"?  A hidden file in Unix is one starting with a dot (`.`).  But your description doesn't mention these.

Comment: Why not: `find $(pwd) -type d -not -name . -exec chmod u=w,g+r,o-rwx "{}" \;` and `find $(pwd) -type f -exec chmod u+x "{}" \;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling whitespace in file names is tricky.  First rule is: doublequotes around all *usages* of variables.  Otherwise the shell interprets the spaces as separators.  Unfortunately you cannot simply hold a list in a variable.  You have to use array variables for this.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=( "$(pwd)"/* )

for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then chmod u+x "$f"; fi
  if [ -d "$f" ]; then chmod u=w,g+r,o-rwx "$f"; fi
done
```

For handling *hidden* files and folders (the ones starting with a dot `.`) you should best set the shell option `dotglob` which makes `*` also match these (which it otherwise doesn't).  (Using `.*` is not good as it matches also `.` and `..` which normally aren't wanted and things like `.??*` will not match stuff like `.a` which is normally wanted.):

```
shopt -s dotglob
FILES=( "$(pwd)"/* )
shopt -u dotglob
```

I would not recommend leaving it on, so I switch it off after using it.

Comment: Why the `pwd` though? Also, you might want to add `shopt -s dotglob` to glob even hidden files.

Comment: Copied from the Q.  Maybe OP plans to use arbitrary lists of file names instead of this.  Otherwise a `for f in *` would be enough.

Comment: @PesaThe The dotglob:  Right, but I somehow have the feeling that OP didn't really mean what most people understand by "hidden" files.  At least he doesn't mention this in the description, so I rather asked for a clarification on this.

Comment: Yep, let's wait for OP to clarify. Maybe OP just didn't realize `*` will not glob hidden files by default. @NahuelFouilleul `.*` will glob even `.` and `..`. That might not be desirable.

Comment: He's having two different problems: 1) it doesn't process hidden files, because of the way globbing works, and 2) it gets errors with files that have whitespace, because of the missing quotes.

Comment: `setopt`? You probably meant `shopt`?

Comment: @pesathe Oh my.  Of course.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Would have been quite okay to fix that yourself.  Fixed it now.

Comment: True. Not enough rep but I still should have suggested an edit, sorry.